# C++ Sleep function doesn't work as is expected

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sleep

I'm going to first draw a `polygon` on the window and after one second remove that `polygon` and draw a `circle` instead.
I wrote this code for it:

```
#include <Simple_window.h>
#include <Graph.h>

using namespace Graph_lib;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    Simple_window win(Point(100,100),600,400,"lines");

    Graph_lib::Polygon poly;
    Circle c(Point(100,150), 50);

    poly.add(Point(100,100));
    poly.add(Point(150,150));
    poly.add(Point(50,100));
    win.attach(poly);
    Sleep(1000);
    win.detach(poly);
    win.attach(c);
    win.wait_for_button();
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't occur this way in practice. In fact the system just waits one second and shows the `circle (c)` only and the `polygon (poly)` will not be shown!

How to solve the problem please?

Comment: Try displaying Polygon first, without sleep and circle. Ensure that Polygon is showing up at all.

Comment: When you use sleep inside your main function you are freezing your main thread. Try incorporating a timer instead

Comment: Yes I tested it and `polygon` was displayed.

Comment: @RedSerpent: You say if I move the `Sleep()` to another function and call that function from `main()`, will the problem be solved?

Comment: @Aria That will not work since again `Sleep()` will also be called in the main thread. The answer to your question is not as simple as you might think and it requires knowledge of how Windows communicate graphics and how and when they are drawn.

Comment: @Aria I would suggest starting to understand the [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145137.aspx) message

Comment: What framework are you using?  I have no idea where `Simple_Window` comes from, so I don't know if it has easy access to the correct functions to make this simple to do.

Comment: I have installed FLTK as graphic tools on my visual studio. Simple_window is [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/).

Answer (score 2):

Call Sleep function inside your main will freeze the application, and repaint/refresh at all.

To do what yiu need you have to use a timer or a thread used as timer where to put your code and manage delays.

Code inside your timer event could be like this

Call Sleep function inside your main will freeze the application, and repaint/refresh at all.

To do what yiu need you have to use a timer or a thread used as timer where to put your code and manage delays.

Code inside your timer event could be like this, I know the code is not correct at all, it is a trace.

```
Graph_lib::Polygon poly;
Circle c;

void OnTimerEvent()
{
      win.detach(poly);
      win.attach(c);
}

int main()
{
    c(Point(100,150), 50);
    poly.add(Point(100,100));
    poly.add(Point(150,150));
    poly.add(Point(50,100));
    win.attach(poly);

    timer.interval = 1000;
    timer.enabled = true;

    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

What I mean is that you have to launch a timer which event will be called after 1 second and can do your stuff.

Comment: I used, `clock_t endwait;` `endwait = clock () + 1 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;` `while (clock() < endwait) {}` instead of `Sleep()` but same result! :(

Comment: I'm not able to give ou code for visual C++. BTW the simpliest way is to  ind timer component in your IDE and use it insted of main function.

Comment: Thank you all for negative vote. I appreciate you for it more than a correct answer.

Comment: It has errors. E.g., `win` is unknown for `OnTimerEvent` function. Please don't delete my comments.

Comment: Yes. Make it global as first test

Comment: It causes errors. It's not possible to have a `win` globally.